# PHP POST request - not able to get the first row MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am currently creating an image gallery website, and somehow no matter what I do, the first image that I posted on the system is always unavailable. I have this 'show info' button on the image, which does a post request that calls on the showinfo.php.

This is the display.php that displays all available image in the database.

```
if ($method == "0") {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM image");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo "
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row text-center' style='display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;'>";
        while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-4'>
                    <div class='thumbnail'>
                        <img src='".$target_dir.$row2['filename']."'>
                        <div class='caption'>
                            <h4>".$row2['name']."</h4>
                        </div>  
                        <p>
                            <form action='showinfo.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                                <input type='hidden' name='image_id' value='".$row2['id']."'>
                                <button name='showinfo' class='btn btn-primary'>More Info</button>
                            </form>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>";
            }
    echo "</div> </div>";
}
```

This is how it looks like on the webpage, notice that the first image/first row of the table in mysql will still be fetched:

[image: display.php preview on html]

And when click on the 'more info' button, it will redirect to the showinfo.php, which shows something like this:

[image: showinfo.php preview on html]

However, it never works for the first image. I have done some testings, it never gets to the showinfo.php page and it will always redirect back to the homepage after I click the button. I have used postman to do a post request, setting the image_id to 1 and that gets me the info page of the first image, just not when the button is clicked. I am using XAMPP 5.6.37

This is the expected result I should get for the first image
[image: This is the expected result I should get for the first image]

Ignore the jammed up stuff.. but the post request goes through.

[This is the showinfo.php code](https://pastebin.com/5NvmFZSr)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the source code of the display page, after accessing the page? Does the first picture have the expected value in the `image-id` input?

Comment: @Geshode The output of `var_dump($_POST)` shows the correct value for `image_id`.

Comment: @Ukiitomi can you add the results of a `var_dump($row)` on the showinfo.php page for both `image_id=1` and `image_id=2`?

Comment: The very only way to get back from showinfo.php is when condition -> if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { is false. As the sql is simpliest possible (SELECT * FROM image where id = ?) the wrong id must be the reason. Dump the id, dump the sql, look into base and check the id of this particular record.

Comment: Would be keen to see the code from a "right mouse click" -> Inspect Element on "Baby Cat" compared to "Baby Pug" (updated in the question, not as a comment).

Comment: @SvenLiivak If that's false, it wouldn't show `Image name: Baby Cat` at all. So the query must be succeeding. The strange thing is that the same `$row['filename']` is used when displaying the gallery and the result, but it's broken in the result.

Comment: Check what image path this actually outputs in the HTML, check what the browser console has to say.

Comment: Sorry, got it wrong: the condition which gives false is: if (isset($_POST['showinfo'])) {

Comment: @SvenLiivak `var_dump($_POST)` shows that this is set to an empty string. Don't you see that it's showing part of the result, but the image is broken?

Comment: Barmar and Ukiitomi, read carefully: _it never gets to the showinfo.php page and it will always redirect back to the homepage_ . Now: there is only ONE piece of code which redirects back to "homepage" and it's behind condition ((isset($_POST['showinfo']).  @Barmar: read, the screenshot without picture is result of postman.

Comment: Get rid of that redirect in `showinfo.php` and display more useful information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the suggestions. Someone mentioned that I should try to take our the redirect code to see why the problem is happening. I did that, and I was able to get the first image's info without any issue. So I look into the code on my homepage ... It turns out it's none of the issues we talked about. On my homepage I have wrapped around the "method" selection code in a form, which is why it's causing that problem. My code originally look like this, and the showImages(this.value) is a js function that will call the display.php shown above.

The div with the id "showimage" is where all the thumbnails show up.
Once I take out the , I was able to solve my issue.

```
  <form>
        <div class='form-inline'>
            <input class='form-control' type='text' id='menu_search_input' size='50' placeholder="enter content first if searching by name..">
                <select class='form-control' id='menu_search' onchange='showImages(this.value)'>
                    <option value=''>Search by</option>
                    <option value='0'>Search by Latest</option>
                    <option value='1'>Search by Image Name</option>
                    <option value='2'>Search by Category</option>
                    <option value='3'>Search by Most Popular</option>
                    <option value='4'>Search by Least Popular</option>
                    <option value='5'>Search by Most Credit Needs</option>
                    <option value='6'>Search by Least Credit Needs</option>
                </select>
            <div id="showimage">Loading images ...</div>
        </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using form to show data of that product on next page what if user copy link and share it to somewhere else it will not have it's post data in it and result will be error page with no data. So far better way to use it.

```
if ($method == "0") {
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM image");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
echo "
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row text-center' style='display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;'>";
    while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-4'>
                <div class='thumbnail'>
                    <img src='".$target_dir.$row2['filename']."'>
                    <div class='caption'>
                        <h4>".$row2['name']."</h4>
                    </div>  
                    <p>
                            <a href='showinfo.php?image_id=".$row2['id']."'> <button name='showinfo' class='btn btn-primary'>More Info</button></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>";
        }
echo "</div> </div>";
}
```

on showinfo.php page you can use $_GET['image_id'] to get data from mysql as per image id and will work globally everywhere with link.

Comment: Why would this fix the problem?

Comment: If it will not solve he will have to show his code in showinfo.php file since there is i seems issue can be since what he have done yet on gallery page it all seems good but i could not let him know on comments due to new account. this way it can be more flexible than using form to post id for just that image id is not good practice.